# Find all functions $f$ satisgying the $3$ definite integrals

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let $a \in [0,1].$ Find all functions $f:[0,1] \to [0,\infty)$ such that $$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=1$$$$\int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx=a$$ and $$\int_{0}^{1}x^2f(x)dx=a^2$$ I am having problems on how to start. Please give some hints. Thanks.

Comment: All such functions?  You can find a quadratic example easily enough...but general functions?

Comment: @User_1upono As lulu says there can be any number of functions. Any function with three parameters can be solved to find a solution.

Comment: Just to emphasize:  you can find step functions that work, so long as you have at least three steps.  Let your function be $A$ on $[0,\frac 13]$, $B$ on $(\frac 13, \frac 23]$ and $C$ on $(\frac 23,1]$ and solve for $A,B,C$.  Nothing special about those sub-intervals, of course.

Comment: So, perhaps the best that one can say is to write this as a coset: using @lulu 's comment, one could find $g(x)=bx^2+cx+d$ that satisfies all the conditions.  Then, all functions $f$ can be written as $g(x)+h(x)$ where $h(x)$ is any function such that $\int_0^1h(x)dx=0$, $\int_0^1xh(x)dx=0$, and $\int_0^1x^2h(x)dx=0$ (of which there are infinitely many).

Comment: @lulu please see the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hölder's inequality implies that for functions $g(x)$ and $h(x)$,
$$
\left(\int_0^1 g(x)h(x)\,dx\right)^2\leq \int_0^1 g(x)^2dx \cdot \int_0^1 h(x)^2 dx,
$$
with equality if and only if $g(x)$ is a scalar multiple of $h(x)$.

**Hint**: In your situation, take $g(x)=\sqrt{f(x)}$ and $h(x)=x\sqrt{f(x)}$.

Answer (score 0):

In the modified question, we have $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. Then we can think of $f$ as a probability density function. The given constraints say that the variance of this distribution is zero (i.e $E[X^2]=E[X]^2$).

Thus, the distribution is concentrated on one value, which is $a$.

This implies that $F(x)=1$ if $x \geq a$ and $F(x)=0$ otherwise, where $F(x)=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$.

However there is no function $f$ for which the above is true, thus ruling out solutions in the case that $f$ is non-negative.

Comment: That function integrates to $0$. Did you mean to describe a delta function centered at $a$?  But anyway, the OP never specified that $f(x)≥0$.

Comment: There's useful information here, but you can't say the solution is what you say! There is no such function. You've shown that there is _no_ solution, assuming $f\ge0$.

Comment: @lulu, thanks. Hope the edit works. And yes, the OP didn't mention that $f(x) \geq 0$, but without that, I think there may be infinitely many solutions.

Comment: No...again, the derivative of a step function is a delta function (aka not a function).  Your argument correctly proves that we can't have $f(x)≥0$ on the interval.  If you drop that condition then there certainly are infinitely many examples (some of which are mentioned in the comments).

Comment: As it stands, your post is not correct.  You shouldn't leave it up like this.  The argument that no such function exists if you add the constraint that $f(x)≥0$ is a good one, and if you edit your post to reflect that this is what you are proving, then it does contribute.  But as it stands it is badly misleading.

Comment: @Aravind Please see the edit.